# Is there a way to define single fields that are never indexed in firestore in all collections

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I understand that index has a cost in firestore. Most of the time we simply store objects without really caring about index and even if we don’t want most of the fields to be indexed.

If I understand correctly, any field at any level are indexed. I.e. for the following document in pseudo json

```
{
  "root_field1": "abc"  (indexed)
  "root_field2": "def"  (indexed)
  "root_field3": {
    "Sub_field1: "ghi" (indexed)
    "sub_field2: "jkl" (indexed)
    "sub_field3: {
      "Inner_field1: "mno" (indexed)
      "Inner_field2: "pqr" (indexed)
   }
}
```

Let’s assume that I have the following record

```
{
 "name": "abc"
 "birthdate": "2000-01-01"
 "gender": "m"
}
```

Let’s assume that I just want the field "name" to be indexed. One solution (A), without having to specify every field is to define it this way (i.e. move the root fields to a sub level `unindexed`), and exclude `unindexed` from being indexed

```
{
 "name": "abc"
 "unindexed" {
   "birthdate": "2000-01-01"
   "gender": "m"
}
```

Ideally I would like to just specify a prefix such as `_` to prevent each field to be indexed but there is no global solution for that.

```
{
 "name": "abc"
 "_birthdate": "2000-01-01"
 "_gender": "m"
}
```

Is my solution (A) correct and is there a more elegant generic solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Accordinig to the documentation
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing

**Add a single-field index exemption**

> Single-field index exemptions allow you to override automatic index
> settings for specific fields in a collection. You can add a
> single-field exemptions from the console:

1. Go to the Single Field Indexes section.
2. Click Add Exemption.
3. Enter a Collection ID and Field path.
4. Select new indexing settings for this field. Enable or disable
   automatically updated ascending, descending, and array-contains
   single-field indexes for this field.

   Click Save Exemption.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I proposed in my solution A (exempt a single top level field named "unindexed" containing sub objects). What about if I have objects with 100 fields and multiple collections ID. Having to define each field for each collection is a pain so I wonder if there is a more generic solution